# Get a certificate from Azure Key Vault in Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault, azure-authentication

I have a certificate stored in my Azure Key Vault. I need to create a logic app in the same subscription to use this certificate to authenticate with an Azure App Service web API end point, using AAD. How do I retrieve the certificate from the logic app? I am hoping I can get it directly from the logic app somehow without having to download it locally and re-upload to the Logic App.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the REST API - [`Get Certificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getcertificate/getcertificate) in the logic app to retrieve the certificate, follow the steps below.

1.[Enable system-assigned identity of the logic app in Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity#enable-system-assigned-identity-in-azure-portal)

2.Navigate to the `Access policies` of your keyvault, add the system-assigned identity to it with the correct `Certificate Permissions`, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal).

3.In the logic app, use the `HTTP` operation like below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This method will only retrieve the public key which, in client authentication, is not enough. You can retrieve the private key as a secret under the same name as the stored certificate. Note that you won't need the password anymore because keyvault stripped it (https://itnext.io/storing-and-retrieving-third-party-certificates-in-azure-key-vault-c8a0a0e6c525). An alternative is to encode the PFX with password to base64 and store that as a secret.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm getting error like - The provided authentication certificate is missing the private key. The private key is required to sign the request.

Answer (score 0):

Store your certificates in Key Vault, but if you want to use in a Logic App, the built-in Key Vault actions won't help. You have to resort to HTTP calls to the REST API!